# Please help me optimize MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

This query is very slow:

```
SELECT  

    ( 
        SELECT SUM(ile.gross)                   
        FROM item_ledger_entry AS ile 
        WHERE clr.docNr=ile.docNr 
        AND clr.serialNo=ile.serialNo 
        AND clr.productNr=ile.productNr 
        AND (ile.cargoLine=clr.id OR ile.orgLine=clr.id) 
        AND ile.id NOT IN (
                            SELECT MIN(zz.id) 
                            FROM item_ledger_entry AS zz 
                            WHERE zz.docNr=ile.docNr 
                            AND zz.serialNo=ile.serialNo 
                            AND zz.productNr=ile.productNr
                          ) 
        AND Date_format(ile.activityDate, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2019-08-05' 
        AND ile.status='40' 
    ) AS gross_end_out

FROM cargo_line_receive AS clr 

LEFT JOIN cargo_header_receive AS chr 
ON clr.docNr=chr.docNr  

LEFT JOIN n_items AS ni 
ON clr.productNr=ni.code 

LEFT JOIN item_ledger_entry AS i 
ON clr.docNr=i.docNr AND i.status=40 
AND (i.id=clr.id OR i.orgLine=clr.id)   


WHERE ((clr.status='20' OR clr.status='30') && clr.status!='40')  

AND Date_format(clr.activityDate, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2019-08-05' 

GROUP BY clr.id, clr.docNr, clr.batchNo, clr.serialNo, clr.productNr
ORDER BY clr.activityDate DESC, clr.id DESC
```

Also i need to see only result **where gross_end_out > 0**

**EDIT:** As requested i add table structure:

cargo_header_receive:

```
CREATE TABLE `cargo_header_receive` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `docNr` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `docNr` (`docNr`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

cargo_line_receive:

```
CREATE TABLE `cargo_line_receive` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `docNr` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `batchNo` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT '',
    `serialNo` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT '',
    `productNr` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   
    `activityDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `orgLine` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `docNr` (`docNr`),
    INDEX `serialNo` (`serialNo`),
    INDEX `productNr` (`productNr`),
    INDEX `status` (`status`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

item_ledger_entry:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_ledger_entry` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `docNr` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cargoLine` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `activityDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `productNr` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `orgLine` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
    `serialNo` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT '0',   
    `gross` DECIMAL(20,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `cargoLine` (`cargoLine`),
    INDEX `orgLine` (`orgLine`),
    INDEX `docNr` (`docNr`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

n_items:

```
CREATE TABLE `n_items` (
    `code` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Using explain:

```
id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys           | key   | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | PRIMARY            | clr   | ALL  | status                  |       |         |                    | 3043 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  | PRIMARY            | chr   | ref  | docNr                   | docNr | 153     | database.clr.docNr | 1    | Using where; Using index
1  | PRIMARY            | i     | ref  | PRIMARY,orgLine,docNr   | docNr | 752     | database.clr.docNr | 5    | Using where
2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ile   | ref  | cargoLine,orgLine,docNr | docNr | 752     | func               | 5    | Using where
3  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | zz    | ref  | docNr                   | docNr | 752     | database.ile.docNr | 5    | Using where
```

Also i cant use gross_end_out in `WHERE`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix is to provide a decent 'composite' index for

```
                        SELECT MIN(zz.id) 
                        FROM item_ledger_entry AS zz 
                        WHERE zz.docNr=ile.docNr 
                        AND zz.serialNo=ile.serialNo 
                        AND zz.productNr=ile.productNr
```

Namely:

```
INDEX(docNr, serialNo, productNr, id)
```

Avoid hiding columns inside functions when they are used in `WHERE` clauses:

```
AND Date_format(activityDate, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2019-08-05'
```

-->

```
AND activityDate < '2019-08-05' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(This may or may not help significantly, depending on whether we can create a useful index involving `activityDate`.)

Now to tackle

```
    WHERE clr.docNr=ile.docNr 
    AND clr.serialNo=ile.serialNo 
    AND clr.productNr=ile.productNr 
    AND (ile.cargoLine=clr.id OR ile.orgLine=clr.id)
    AND ile.activityDate < '2019-08-05' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND ile.status='40'
```

The Optimizer may start with `clr`, or it may start with `ile`.  In case it picks `ile`, then add

```
ile: INDEX(status, activityDate) -- in this order
clr: INDEX(docNr, serialNo, productNr)  -- in any order
```

For `clr`, add

```
ile: INDEX(docNr, serialNo, productNr,  -- in any order, plus
           status, activityDate         -- in this order
```

This:

```
    ON clr.docNr=i.docNr AND i.status=40
```

Needs

```
i:  INDEX(docNr, status)  -- in either order
```

Also, don't blindly use `VARCHAR(250)`; it can hurt performanc slightly in subtle ways.  Pick a reasonable (but conservative) limit based on the data you have and might eventually have.

Are there other columns in `n_items`?  If not, why does the table exist?  And why have the `LEFT JOIN` to it?

More on composite indexes and other things:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Are there other columns in `n_items`? Yes every table have columns that are returned in select i just did took em out of select. Checking your answer now!

Comment: At the end i did not used this way. But this helped me allot! Thanks!!!